# What does "freshness bonus" mean and how do I get it?

Tags: splatoon-2

Earlier today after one of my games, the game awarded me a bonus 3000 experience with the description "freshness bonus". Under what circumstances does the game award this bonus?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In junction to @Vemonus's answer, the [wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/splatoon-2/Freshness_Bonus) adds a bit different wording plus a nice graph.

> A Freshness Bonus in Splatoon 2 refers to the proficiency you've earned for each individual weapon. This is different from Judd's coin bonus from the original game.
>
> Each weapon has a freshness rating that will improve every time you win a match. It starts at 0 and goes up one point each time you win a match. Losing a match will subtract from your score, but how much it subtracts depends on your current rating. Once you reach a certain amount, a point bonus is applied.
>
> Take note that while your ranking will continue to go up, the highest you can go is SUPERFRESH! along with all three one time bonuses.

[image: Graph of bonuses]

Comment: It actually looks like you get a 3000 bonus at Raw and a 4500 bonus at Fresh per weapon, according to my own experience getting to Raw on dualies and Fresh on aerospray

Comment: @Unionhawk I'll update that when I get a chance

Comment: The "loss" column is slightly off.  You lose 0.5/game at Dry, 1 once you reach Raw, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[This Twinfinite article](http://twinfinite.net/2017/07/splatoon-2-freshness-bonus-how-to-get-it-and-what-it-is/) explains the Freshness bonus pretty well:

> **Your Freshness Rating is all about bonuses and is tied to two things: your weapon and your ability to win matches.** If you can excel at winning and using a specific weapon, you can earn a Freshness Bonus which is a large amount of experience points to help you level up faster.
>
> Each weapon has its own rating, so if you want to build the rating you need to stick to a gun, preferably one you’re really good with. **While using that gun, its rating will go up every time you win a match by .5 points, but if you lose it can go down a full point. So you need a positive win/loss ration to rank up. If you happen to rank up a weapon during a match, when it’s time to get your rewards you’ll see your Freshness Bonus as a huge splat next to your normal points and it’s always a few thousand.**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>